# Cocoa: Progress Bar Inside Toolbar Text Field

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, progress-bar, toolbar

I am posting today because I want to achieve a similar result to Xcode 7's progress indicator located inside the Toolbar.

[image]

A blue bar is shown beneath what appears to be an `NSTextField` and I thought this would be a stock UI element but I could not find something similar in the Object library.

How could one achieve a similar result, preferably using a native `NSProgressIndicator`?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: I managed to have something similar by using the answer in this old question: [NSTextField like safari address bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676555/nstextfield-like-safari-address-bar). <s>But the background becomes white (instead of the light gray gradient) before I resize the window to force re-drawing the text field. Where should I put `self.needsDisplay` in order to refresh the text field once it is initialized? Putting it at the end of `awakeFromNib` doesn't do it.</s>
Actually this works brilliantly after I added a few `needsDisplay` in the `didSet`s so I guess it's solved! Don't forget to set the `viewController` property at some point if you want to have it as target for the button.

```
import Cocoa

class ToolbarTextField: NSTextField {

    var button = NSButton()
    var inProgress: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            self.needsDisplay = true
            self.button.hidden = !self.inProgress
            self.button.needsDisplay = true
            self.button.enabled = true
        }
    }
    var progress: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            self.needsDisplay = true
            self.button.needsDisplay = true
        }
    }
    var viewController: NSViewController? = nil {
        didSet {
            self.button.target = self.viewController
            self.button.action = "cancelLoadingButtonClicked:"
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let buttonFrame = NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 16.0)
        self.button = NSButton(frame: buttonFrame)

        self.button.setButtonType(NSButtonType.MomentaryChangeButton)
        self.button.bezelStyle = NSBezelStyle.RegularSquareBezelStyle
        self.button.bordered = false
        self.button.imagePosition = NSCellImagePosition.ImageOnly
        self.button.image = NSImage(named: NSImageNameStopProgressFreestandingTemplate)
        self.button.hidden = !self.inProgress

        self.addSubview(self.button)
    }

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

        if self.inProgress {
            let buttonFrame = NSMakeRect(self.bounds.size.width - 22, ceil((self.bounds.size.height / 2) - 9), 16.0, 16.0)
            self.button.frame = buttonFrame

            var progressRect = self.bounds
            progressRect.origin.y = progressRect.size.height - 4
            progressRect.size.height = 2
            progressRect.size.width *= self.progress

            NSColor.alternateSelectedControlColor().set()
            NSRectFillUsingOperation(progressRect, NSCompositingOperation.CompositeSourceIn)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually managed to do it myself, please see the code in the question.

Don't forget to set the `viewController` property to your button target (it was the view controller in my case) after initializing the text field.

Answer (score 1):

I have not done this myself but my guess is that this is a custom `NSView` inside the toolbar that draws the white box. Inside that view there are the text fields, little error images and the custom designed progress indicator.

Of course you can use the stock `NSProgressIndicator`, but to get exactly the design of Xcode, you have to subclass it.

Comment: I edited my question to include an attempted answer. I was able to subclass `NSTextField` and obtain a similar result but I am facing a new issue with the background being totally white before the view gets re-drawn.